# Why is my unpivot query on Athena not working? I just followed the samples online but i always get `mismatched input ...`

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, unpivot, trino

I have a table that looks like

| date | oil | gas | petroleum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01 | 100 | 90 | 80 |
| 2022-02 | 90 | 90 | 90 |

and using this query:

```
select * from source.table UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS
(value for type in ("oil", "gas", "petroleum"))
```

I want it to look like

| date | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01 | oil | 100 |
| 2022-01 | gas | 90 |
| 2022-01 | petroleum | 80 |
| 2022-02 | oil | 90 |
| 2022-02 | gas | 90 |
| 2022-02 | petroleum | 90 |

but instead I'm getting this error

```
line 1:52: mismatched input 'INCLUDE'. Expecting: '(', ',', 'CROSS', 'EXCEPT', 'FULL', 'GROUP', 'HAVING', 'INNER', 'INTERSECT', 'JOIN', 'LEFT', 'LIMIT', 'NATURAL', 'OFFSET', 'ORDER', 'RIGHT', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'UNION', 'WHERE', <EOF>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `UNPIVOT` function in [Presto](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/search.html?q=unpivot)/[Trino](https://trino.io/docs/current/search.html?q=UNPIVOT) on which AWS Athena is based. You need to unpivot "manually", for example using arrays and `unnest`:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(date, oil, gas, petroleum) as(
    values ('2022-01', 100, 90, 80),
        ('2022-02', 90, 90, 90)
)

-- query
select date, type, value
from dataset,
    unnest(array['oil', 'gas', 'petroleum'], array[oil, gas, petroleum]) as t(type, value);
```

Output:

| date | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01 | oil | 100 |
| 2022-01 | gas | 90 |
| 2022-01 | petroleum | 80 |
| 2022-02 | oil | 90 |
| 2022-02 | gas | 90 |
| 2022-02 | petroleum | 90 |